# Run query against all databases with a similar name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have 30 databases on a server. I need to run a query against 20 of them. I wrote some code to handle this, but it is bombing out so I was looking for advice on how to correct this or change how i am doing it.

Error information:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near 'hr'.

The databases that I need to run against all have similar names:

```
CustDB00001
CustDB00025
CustDB00076
CustDB09999
```

My code:

```
set nocount on;

DECLARE @db_name NVARCHAR (150)

DECLARE c_db_names CURSOR FOR
    SELECT name 
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE name like ('Billing%')

OPEN c_db_names    

FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name    

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0    
BEGIN
    EXEC('INSERT INTO #B1report   
              SELECT 
                  hr.client,
                  RTRIM(LTRIM(hc.facility)) AS facility,
                  h.gcode, h.rcode,
                  u.bill,
                  hr.*
              FROM 
                  CustDB' + dbname + '.dbo.table1 h 
              JOIN 
                  CustDB' + dbname + '.dbo.table2 hr ON hr.[hrcounter] = h.hcounter 
              JOIN 
                  CustDB' + dbname + '.dbo.table3 hc ON hc.[hccounter] = hr.hrcounter 
              JOIN 
                  CustDB' + dbname + '.dbo.table4 u ON u.ucounter = hc.hccounter 
              WHERE 1 = 1 
                AND CAST(2.r_date AS DATE) BETWEEN ''01/01/2017'' AND ''6/18/2018''
                AND 1.rcode IN (''69'', ''70'')')

    FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name
END

CLOSE c_db_names
DEALLOCATE c_db_names

SELECT * FROM #B1report
```

Any suggestions on how to correct the above, or how to handle it better (maybe without a cursor), would be appreciated.

Comment: *it is bombing out* Perhaps you can tell us where/what line/what error message you are getting?

Comment: I edited and plunked in the error code:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RIGHT'.

Comment: `+  RIGHT(CONCAT('00000',dbname),5)) +` you have an extra right parenthesis.

Comment: You are right. However it still blows up, same error message

Comment: `dbname` should also be `@db_name`

Comment: I also removed the Right(Concat section, and just left it as CustDB' +  @db_name + '.dbo.table1 1

Comment: Why not add `WHERE name LIKE 'CustDB%'` to the first query, then you don't need to build up the string yourself? i.e. `FROM ' +  @db_name + '.dbo.table1`

Comment: I don't have an answer for that to be honest with you. I just did what I thought was right. Can you give me a better example, this is totally a learning situation for me.

Comment: I believe something like: Rather than being exclusive with `WHERE name NOT IN('master', 'tempdb')`, why not be inclusive with `WHERE name LIKE 'CustDB%`.

Comment: I am making changes as you all suggest things. I will edit the above to reflect this. I have a new error message as well, which is a sign to me that I am getting closer!

Comment: New error is 
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
    Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Which would put it at the start of the Select

Comment: You probably need to use brackets for the table, since you used a numeric value as the alias.

Comment: I don't believe that using a number for a table alias is legal.  Try using a,b.c,d and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I only use the #'s here, in my actual code I used h, hr, hc, and u as the alias. I didn't want to provide that here, as I hate putting anything remotely close to my table names in here. I will edit the above accordingly

Comment: I suggest using `QUOTENAME`, just just concatenate your strings when using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using all of the above advice. I am firmly into a whole new error now. I am not sure where to start in detailing my answer, but I will try to in the next few minutes